# Интерпретация передаваемых параметров

Tags: java, ооп, классы

В процессе ООП на Java решаю задачу с перемещением робота по координатам. Часть кода и основной класс заданы в условии(привёл ниже). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как трактовать "Robot robot"? Это ведь не тип данных и в поисковике ничего найти не удается.

```
public static void moveRobot(Robot robot, int toX, int toY) {
    robot.stepForward(); // implementation...
}
```

Основной класс:

```
public class Robot {

    public Direction getDirection() {
        // текущее направление взгляда
    }

    public int getX() {
        // текущая координата X
    }

    public int getY() {
        // текущая координата Y
    }

    public void turnLeft() {
        // повернуться на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки
    }

    public void turnRight() {
        // повернуться на 90 градусов по часовой стрелке
    }

    public void stepForward() {
        // шаг в направлении взгляда
        // за один шаг робот изменяет одну свою координату на единицу
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Robot` - это тип передаваемого параметра, а `robot` ссылка на объект, передаваемый в метод. Т.е это почти то же самое, что и `int toX`. `Java` всегда передаёт параметры по значению, но так как параметр `robot` - объект, то через эту передачу можно получить доступ к его полям и менять их значение внутри метода `move()`

```
...
Robot robot1 = new Robot(...);
Robot robot2 = new Robot(...);
...
moveRobot(robot1, 10, 20);
moveRobot(robot2, 20, 30);
```